# how to specify unique repository id per each project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, maven-deploy-plugin

I am reading the apache maven instruction about how to [deploy eclipse project](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html) and how to configure pom.xml and .m2/settings.xml for this purpose...

pom.xml

```
[...]
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>internal.repo</id>
      <name>MyCo Internal Repository</name>
      <url>Host to Company Repository</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
[...]
```

and the .m2/settings.xml

```
[...]
    <server>
      <id>internal.repo</id>
      <username>maven</username>
      <password>foobar</password>
    </server>
[...]
```

the thing is the settings.xml is just one file which is about to contain the repo id to login etc...
so my question is... is there a way to switch in eclipse between maven projects (dedicated for deployment) and not to edit the settings.xml (the ticket) for each project in separate?

Thanks

Comment: First why do you need a different repository for each of your projects? Usually you use a single repository and separate them by using different groupId/artifactId/version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what are you asking. And I don't really know what Eclipse has to do with it.

If I understand correctly, your concern is that different project will need to use different repositories. If so, just configure all the repositories in the [servers](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers) section of your `settings.xml`. Then each POM can reference the server it needs by its ID.

If that is not what you are asking, please update the question to explain exactly what you are trying to do and what is the problem you are facing.